# Configuring wsgi application to serve a static html?

Tags: python, wsgi, openshift-online-2

I'm looking to install www.planetplanet.org in openshift.  I've hosted a few php apps on openshift, but am not sure how python apps work.  The openshift template gives me a wsgi.py file, which needs the 'application' module / function as its starting point.  I'm not sure where to point it to.  The planetplanet code layout is [here](https://people.gnome.org/~jdub/bzr/planet/devel/trunk/) and my suspicion is I have to point the 'application' to planet/**init**.py.  No idea though how to do it.

While searching, I came across https://github.com/shekhargulati/schedapp-openshift which is a simple python app on openshift, which has this line in its wsgi.py:

```
from sched.app import app as application, db
```

But planetplanet doesn't seem to be a module that can be loaded in such a way.

I tried:

```
from planet.planet import planet as application
```

but that fails with this message on the server:

```
ImportError: No module named planet.planet
```

EDIT:
I found planetplanet just dumps a static index.html in my output directory, so I now just need to ensure wsgi application points to my output dir to serve the html.

Any pointers / advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did something like this:

```
response_body = open(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'] + 'planet/virt/output/index.html').read()
```

in the default

```
def application
```

part of the wsgi.py script.  That got the static html to work, but obviously without css.

But then I discovered openshift provides the python binary in non-python apps as well, so I just created a DIY application, imported the planetplanet sources, and used the python in the cron script to update the feeds; and the default testrubyserver.rb in the diy/ dir to serve the index.html.

Answer (score 0):

in the default 
`def application`
add

```
ctype = 'text/html'
open(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR']+'/blabla.html')
```

Important : don't not forget 'text/html' return type.